# Getting System.ArgumentException when running C# Selenium Test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, selenium-webdriver

I'm learning how to write selenium tests in C# and am getting this error when trying to run the test case below.  It is failing on: IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));

```
Test method SeleniumDemo.SearchGoogle.SearchForCheese threw exception: 
System.ArgumentException: elementDictionary (Parameter 'The specified dictionary does not contain an element reference')
```

Code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SearchForCheese()
{

    using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)))
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");


        // Find text input
        IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        query.SendKeys("cheese");

        // Submit form
        query.Submit();

        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until(d => d.Title.Contains("cheese"));

        Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "cheese - Google Search");
    };
}
```

Any ideas?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've written my fair share of Selenium tests and the answer isn't obvious to me, but [this code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/f812eddf62097ac4544471a4c16432d821ee9882/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebElementFactory.cs#L82), and similar, appears to be what throws that exception.  Seems related to a missing element ID.  Not sure if this helps but it's something.  I personally would debug and step through the Selenium code.

Answer (score 1):

Check and make sure your `ChromeDriver()` version matches what is on your local machine.

Below is an XUnit test that will re-create your issue using the [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/rosolko/WebDriverManager.Net) NuGet package where you can manually specify which version of webdriver you want downloaded if it's not available on your machine:

```
    [Fact]
    public void ChromeDriverThrows_ArgumentException_True()
    {
        var google = "https://www.google.com/";
        var message = "elementDictionary (Parameter 'The specified 
                        dictionary does not contain an element 
                         reference')";

        // Specify a different of ChromeDriver than what is installed on machine.
        _ = new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(
                      "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.25/chromedriver_win32.zip",
                     Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "chromedriver.exe"),
                      "chromedriver.exe"
                     );

        var driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(google);

        var exception = Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")));

        Assert.True(message == exception.Message, $"{exception.Message}");
    }
```

If you choose to use `WebDriverManager` in your project, you can use automatically set the below to automatically download a chromedriver.exe matching the version of Chrome installed in your machine so you don't have to manually manage them:

```
new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig(), VersionResolveStrategy.MatchingBrowser);
```